# Unable to create a new hotfix in SourceTree gitflow

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow, hotfix

[image]

Hello this is my git workflow. I'm trying to create by using Sourcetree a new hotfix. Unfortunately I get this error:

```
There is an existing hotfix branch (issue-#001). Finish that one first.
```

I have already finished the `issue-#001`. Why I'm unable to create a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delete the existing branch with the same name if you want to create it again . Git would not allow you to create branches with duplicate names.

You can also try to update the hotfix branch by merging in the latest master and then work on the updated branch

Comment: when I create the hotfix branch and then I need to finish it, do I need to delete it?

Comment: Yes, ideally you need to delete it after you merge back into master

Comment: By default, Gitflow limits only **one** existing hotfix branch, so if all hotfixes get deleted, no matter with the same name or not, things can go through.

Answer (score 31):

There is a configuration option that you can set if you want multiple hotfixes.

```
git config --add gitflow.multi-hotfix true
```

This would allow multiple hotfixes, but by default it's not allowed. You can add this option per repository or globally.

Answer (score 3):

Check for existing hotfixes:

```
git branch | grep hotfix
```

It gives you the full name of your hotfix branch, in your case `issue-#001`. Remove the branch if not needed anymore:

```
git branch -D issue-#001
```

To check what the `issue-#001` was about, run

```
git stash
git checkout issue-#001
git status
git diff
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the last `hotfix` that You've created (the branch named only with `hotfix` without the slash), before creating a new one. And you'll receive the following message when you try to create the new `hotfix` (if you're on the `command prompt`):

```
Switched to a new branch 'hotfix/XXXXX'

Summary of actions:
- A new branch 'hotfix/XXXXX' was created, based on 'main'
- You are now on branch 'hotfix/XXXXX'

Follow-up actions:
- Start committing your hot fixes
- Bump the version number now!
- When done, run:

     git flow hotfix finish 'XXXXX'
```

Run the following command to be able to use multi hotfix branches, if necessary:

```
git config --add gitflow.multi-hotfix true
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like you already have hotfix with this name
check to verify:

```
git branch
```

you should see hotfix/XXXX what ever name you use